# Regex: match expression except

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a condition except when it comes when a specific text. The signature I am using is the following:

```
(?:(?:\%3D)|(?:=))[^\n]*(?:(?:\%27)|(?:\')|(?:\-\-)|(?:\%3B)|(?:;))
```

It first looks out for the = sign or its hex equivalent (%3D). Then it allows for zero or more non-newline characters, and then it checks for the single-quote, the double-dash or the semi-colon.

I want this signature to match everything unless I get an specific TEXT, such as:

```
=TEXT;
```

How can I get it?

Comment: would you plz put some i/o in the post ?

Comment: Try [`(?:%3D|=)(?!TEXT;).*?(?:%27|'|--|%3B|;)`](https://regex101.com/r/70Rsjd/1)

Comment: You might have to repeat the boundaries - https://regex101.com/r/70Rsjd/2

Comment: It worked fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:%3D|=)(?!TEXT(?:%27|'|--|%3B|;)).*?(?:%27|'|--|%3B|;)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/70Rsjd/2)

**Details**

- `(?:%3D|=)` - `%3D` or `=`
- `(?!TEXT(?:%27|'|--|%3B|;))` - there can't be `TEXT` followed with `%27`, `'`, `--`, `%3B` or `;`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:%27|'|--|%3B|;)` - `%27`, `'`, `--`, `%3B` or `;`